# How do I get my application to recognize the app.config file?

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, wcf-binding

This is a concept that has never really been a problem for me until now.  In VB.NET, every application automatically generates an app.config file.  For years I have just ignored them but lately, as I get tasked to do more and more work with web services they seem to be able to play a useful role.  That is mostly with the configuration of bindings and endpoints.  I have done all of this in code in the past but I think it would be useful to use the app.config so that in cases where a port number or IP changes I could just change the element data instead of recompiling the project with the change (I actually currently use appsettings for this but you get the idea - I'd like a more complete solution).

So, my problem is that my applications do not seem to recognize the app.config file when the app is deployed on a computer other than my own.  Currently I get the dreaded 'Could not find default endpoint element that references contract blahblah' which seems to indicate that my endpoint info is not being read.  If I do the same thing in code it works fine.

Is there something extra, beyond just compiling, that I need to do to get the bindings/endpoints etc from app.config to apply?

**Code Example (this works):**

```
Dim epa As New EndpointAddress("https://www.mysite.com/devserviceloc/test1.svc")
Dim binding As New BasicHttpBinding
binding.Name = "secureHttpBinding"
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None
binding.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = HttpProxyCredentialType.None
binding.Security.Transport.Realm = ""
Dim test As New TestingService1.test1Client(binding, epa)
```

**App.config equivalent (does not work)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">

    <requiredRuntime version="v4.0.20506"/>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
          </security >
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
    <endpoint address="https://www.mysite.com/devserviceloc/test1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding" contract="TestingService1.Itest1"
      name="BasicHttpBinding_Itest1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>

  <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: When the application is actually built, it needs to be called YourApplication.exe.config. Are you trying to use the literal `app.config` with your application? If so, you need to rename it to `assemblyname.exe.config` if an EXE or `assemblyname.dll.config` if it's for a DLL. Visual Studio normally does this for you.

Comment: If your web services are being delivered using IIS, then the config file needs to be called Web.config.

Comment: @TyCobb Yes that is exactly what I am trying to do.  I had no idea I had to rename it to match the assembly name.  My IDE does not name it for me - it is always 'app.config'.  (If you had posted as an answer I'd be able to upvote.)

Comment: @DeanOC - I haven't had any troubles with web services on the server side since the web.config is named web.config by default.  My problem is with dlls and exes that could make use of the app.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application is actually built, it needs to be called `YourApplication.exe.config`.

You need to rename it to `assemblyname.exe.config` if an EXE or `assemblyname.dll.config` if it's for a DLL. Visual Studio normally does this for you when you compile. It's still `app.config` in the source folder, but should be renamed in the Debug & Release folders.

[You can see this mentioned here in the **Application Configuration Files** section.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y(v=vs.110).aspx)